# Shadded error bars with texture using matlab

Tags: textures, errorbar

I am using the package shaddedErrorBar (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26311-shadederrorbar) in order to plot physiological data with a shadded error bar. ;)

I managed of course to change the color myself, but unfortunately I do not know how to change the texture of the shadded bar.

Does anyone have a clue how to do that?

Thanks a lot!

Here the code component for blocking:

```
`A=shadedErrorBar(x,y,e,'k',1)`
`x  =  contains the x-values
y = contains the y-values
e= contains the respective standard errors of the mean 
'k' => color 
1 => sets transparency settings `
```

Best wishes, 
Ferdinand